# recover a column used as an index in pandas df

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to join two dataframes by a common column:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Well_n': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
                'Qo_rate': [200, 150, 170, 0],
                'year': [2001, 2002, 2003, 2004]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Well_n': ['A', 'C', 'B', 'D'],
                'Well_ECL': ['P1', 'P3', 'P2', 'P4']})
df1.set_index('Well_n',inplace=True)
df2.set_index('Well_n',inplace=True)
joined = df1.join(df2,on='Well_n')
print(joined)
```

the output I get is :

```
         Qo_rate  year Well_ECL
Well_n                        
A           200  2001       P1
B           150  2002       P2
C           170  2003       P3
D             0  2004       P4
```

However, when I try to index this new dataframe by year I get this:

```
joined.set_index('year')

      Qo_rate Well_ECL
year
2001      200       P1
2002      150       P2
2003      170       P3
2004        0       P4
```

The column `'Well_n'` dissappears. I tried to fine something related with the `set_index` method, but even after using `drop=False`, I get exactly the same result.
the Output I would like is :

```
      Qo_rate Well_ECL  Well_n
year
2001      200       P1   A
2002      150       P2
2003      170       P3
2004        0       P4
```

Comment: why Well_n column contains only A in final output?

Comment: Instead of making `Well_n` an index, leave the index as the default and then do a `pd.merge` instead of `df1.join`

Comment: Why are you doing `df1.set_index('Well_n',inplace=True)`? Is it just because you think it's needed for the join, or is there some other reason?

Comment: my bad Well_n should have A. B . C .D as a column,

Comment: yes, I thought it was needed to define an index for the join

Comment: Dan, merge worked. thanks. I am just now a bit confused between the use of merge and join. As far as I understood, join demands and index column, while merge doesn't. am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First merge both dataframe on `Well_n` then `set_index('year')`

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Well_n': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
                'Qo_rate': [200, 150, 170, 0],
                'year': [2001, 2002, 2003, 2004]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Well_n': ['A', 'C', 'B', 'D'],
                'Well_ECL': ['P1', 'P3', 'P2', 'P4']})
res = pd.merge(df1,df2,on=['Well_n'],how='inner')
res.set_index('year',inplace=True)
```

```
     Well_n Qo_rate Well_ECL
year            
2001    A   200       P1
2002    B   150       P2
2003    C   170       P3
2004    D   0         P4
```